# Bazel returns an error when I invoke standard ops (e.g. MatMul) in my new custom c++ op

Tags: tensorflow

I implemented a new custom c++ op in tensorflow. In corresponding operation kernel's Compute function, some standard ops (e.g. MatMul) is called.
The main source code is:

```cpp
REGISTER_OP("NewOp")
.Input("input: int32")
.Output("output: int32")
.SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
  c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
  return Status::OK();
});

#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"

using namespace tensorflow;
using namespace tensorflow::ops;

class MyNewOp : public OpKernel {
public:
    explicit MyNewOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}
    void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
        // Grab the input tensor
        ……
        // Create an output tensor
        ……
        Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
        auto A = Const(root, { {35.f, 22.f}, {-10.f, 0.f} });
        auto b = Const(root, { {30.f, 55.f} });
        auto v = MatMul(root.WithOpName("v"), A, b, MatMul::TransposeB(true));
        std::vector<Tensor> results;
        ClientSession session(root);
        TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({v}, &results));
        // Set the output tensor according to the results of MatMul
        ……
    }
};
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("NewOp").Device(DEVICE_CPU), MyNewOp);
```

And the corresponding Bazel BUILD file is:

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")
tf_custom_op_library(
    name = "MyNewOp.so",
    srcs = ["mynewop.cc"],
    deps = [
    "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
    "//tensorflow/cc:client_session",
    "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)
```

When I build the above target, Bazel returns error:

```
tensorflow/cc:cc_ops cannot depend on tensorflow/core:framework
```

How can I solve this issues? I would like to know if I can call ternsorflow predefined ops in new custom c++ op? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is because your custom op depends on `tensorflow/core:framework` which is explicitly forbidden by this [rule](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dcb10b1d557168646204239bea6ca5bf1abc40a3/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl#L1311):

```
disallowed_deps=[
      clean_dep("//tensorflow/core:framework"),
      clean_dep("//tensorflow/core:lib")
]
```

The best way would be to find another solution.

If really you want to have this dependency, there is this **hacky way** of which  reimplementing the `tf_custom_op_library` rule without the forbidden dependency.

This could be done for example this way:

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_copts")
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_cc_shared_object")
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "clean_dep")

tf_cc_shared_object(
    name = "MyNewOp.so",
    srcs = ["mynewop.cc"],
    copts = tf_copts(is_external=True),
    linkstatic = 1,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
    "//tensorflow/core:framework",
    "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
    "//tensorflow/cc:client_session",
    "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",],
    linkopts= select({
              "//conditions:default": [
                  "-lm",
              ],
              clean_dep("//tensorflow:windows"): [],
              clean_dep("//tensorflow:windows_msvc"): [],
              clean_dep("//tensorflow:darwin"): [],
          }),
)
```

which works fine:

```
Target //tensorflow/user_ops:MyNewOp.so up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/user_ops/MyNewOp.so
INFO: Elapsed time: 46.399s, Critical Path: 19.71s
INFO: 397 processes, local.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 400 total actions
```

Comment: Hi, @npf, thank you very much for your kindly help. I still have two questions and look forward to your further help.

Comment: 1. I used the new bazel BUILD file you provided, my new op can be built successfully. When I test the op, the following error is occurred: 
[libprotobuf ERROR external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:58] File already exists in database:tensorflow/core/kernels/booosted_trees/boosted_trees.proto
[libprotobuf FATAL  external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1404] CHECK terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘google::protobuf::FatalException’ what(): CHECK failed:generated_database_->Add(encoded_file_decriptor, size):
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: 2. My new custom C++ op need to support both CPU and GPU versions. The CPU version is located at newOp.cc, while the GPU version  is located at newOp_gpu.cu.cc.  I added the parameters, srcs = ["newOp.cc”, “newOp_gpu.cu.cc”], to tf_custom_op_library in bazel BUILD file. When I rebuild it, many variable undeclared errors appeared. For example:
./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_device_function.h:90:35: error: ‘blockidx’ was not declared in this scope 
./tensorflow/core/util/cuda_device_functions.h:90:48: error: ‘blockDim’ was not declared in this scope
Thank you very much.

Comment: @pfm: do you know why these two build rules are forbidden in custom ops?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't.